# Facebook login using xamarin android without install fabook android sdk

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The user interface contain one **go** button only and are code in go.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
         BackgroundColor="Indigo"
         Padding="10,20,0,0"
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ExerciseApp.Login">
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="20">

    <Button Text="Go" Clicked="Entry_Completed"/>

</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

After the Go button was clicked, facebook webpage will open and auto fill in the username and passwords and login automatically, below code are store in go.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Plugin.AutoLogin;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
namespace ExerciseApp
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Login : ContentPage
{

    void Entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.facebook.com"));
        Device.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys("john@hotmail.com");
        Device.FindElement(By.Id("pass")).SendKeys("passjohn");
        Device.FindElement(By.Id("u_0_3")).SendKeys(Key.click);         
    }

    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
}
```

The code are fails to run. Anyone can share me some idea?

Comment: How does it fail? With an exception?

Comment: hello @rene , the error is " the device does not contain FindElement"

Comment: Where did you find that [`Device`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Device/) contains a `FindElement`? Looks like you're mixing with Selenium.

Comment: yes i plan to using the selenium, but i already downlod the package, but still error

Comment: Just remind you to delete the e-mail information.